# Apple Keyboard - remap currency keys

Tags: keyboard, macbookpro

I got a wireless keyboard Apple keybord for my MacBook Pro which has the Swedish keyboard-layout where `shift + 4` prints out the `€` and `alt + E` prints out the `$`. I was used to have the dollar on shift + 4 (using the key a lot while programming) and wonder if it is possible to change only this two key-combinations. So my goal is to get the $ when pressing shift + 4 and the € when pressing alt + E. I did quite a bit of research but did only find ways to change functional keys like cmd or alt but nothing exactly like I need.

**Summary:**
My keyboard is set up in the way that

- `shift + 4` returns `€`
- `shift + E` returns `$`

I would like the keyboard to act this way:

- `shift + 4` returns `$`
- `shift + E` returns `€`

Any ideas how to re-map the keys like that?